# How do I call the function to check in a view?

Tags: codeigniter

How do I check if my database has more than 9 entries, and if it has, I can advance to the next page.
Currently I have this code, but I don't know how to call that in my view:

Here in the controller I have already called the checklogin and see if it has more than 9 entries.
Controller:

```html
 function quizzes(){
  $this->load->model('Quiz_Model');
  $data['categorys'] = $this->Quiz_Model->SearchAllCategorys();
  $this->load->view('headerLogged');
  $this->load->view('quizzes', $data);
  $this->load->view('footer');
 }
 
 function proses_quiz($id_category){
  $this->load->view('headerLogged');

  $checkquiz=$this->Quiz_Model->checkquiz($id_category);
  
  if($checkquiz > 9){
   redirect('User_Ctr/quiz/').$id_category;
  }else{
   $data['error_quiz']="MEH";
   $this->load->view('quizzes', $data);
  }
  $this->load->view('footer');
 }
```

And here it's just the code to make the count:
Model:

```html
 public function checkquiz($id_category){
  $this->db->select('id_question, COUNT(id_question) as total');
  $this->db->from('questions');
  $this->db->where('id_category', $id_category);
  $result = $this->db->get();
  return $result->result();
 }
```

View:

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>

<div class="container">
 <h1 class="my-4 text-center text-lg-left">Quizzes</h1>
 <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">
  <?php foreach($categorys as $cat): ?>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6"  >
    <a href="<?php echo 'quiz/'.$cat->id_category ?>" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" >
     <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="<?php echo $cat->img_category ?>" alt="" style="height: 125px; width: 400px">
     <?php
      if(isset($error_quiz)){
       echo $error_quiz;
      }
     ?>
    </a>
   </div>
   
  <?php endforeach ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: count_all_results?

Comment: @SherifSalah The count is alredy done, I just don't know how do I call the proses_quiz in my view when I click the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer you question generally.

If you want to call something in the view you have many options like you have the variable already calculated in advance and already passed it to view waiting for a call, or you can click on a link that maybe reload the current view with the new variable done, or you can use ajax to go get the variable from the controller without reloading.

So if the variable has fixed value that doesn't depend on your action, go with the first option or else chose one of the others.